# fopen() failed to read/write Mac Big Sur

Tags: php, error-handling

I am brand new to learning PHP. I keep receiving an error code when trying to run my code in google chrome.
As seen here:

> failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/class_projects/ch2/processorder.php on line 68

I followed some instructions I found to do the following in the terminal:

`sudo chmod -R _www:_www/var/www/html/class_projects/ch2/processorder.php`

I also tried:
`chmod 777`
;to no beneficial effect either.

I tried re-running the page after this action in the terminal. I still receive the same error code.
What is my next best step in approaching this issue? I'm sure it's something I'm overlooking. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: What's it trying to do on line 68? The issue isn't with permissions on the PHP file itself, but rather something it's doing on line 68....

Comment: your `chmod` command, why there's no space between `_www:_www` and the path? Are you sure that `_www` are correct user and group names configured in httpd.conf, did you check that?

Comment: While using `chmod` with `-R` option why you are pointing single file instead of the whole root folder?

Comment: `sudo chmod -R _www:_www /var/www/...` should be `sudo chown -R _www:_www /var/www/...` I think

Comment: @cOle2       I am trying to append a file. Line 68 appears as follows `$fp = fopen("$document_root/class_projects/ch2/orders.txt", 'ab');`